# Current activity logger

Tags: bash, cron, alert

Does anyone know of an app (for iOS or Mac) that asks for my current activity every hour or so? I see tons of apps that let you log your activities, but none that use popups/notifications to actively ask you.

I found a script that looks promising ([source](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2006/08/11/time-logging-script/)), but I'm having trouble implementing it so that it repeats every hour:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo What are you doing right now?
read -e what
echo `date` - $what >> timelog.txt
```

Comment: Maybe do a cron job for this ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the whole thing in a while loop and have it sleep for 1 hour after asking:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    echo What are you doing right now?
    read -e what
    echo `date` - $what >> timelog.txt
    sleep 3600
done
```

Answer (score 0):

you could set that script up as a cron job. Here's a SE question on how to do it

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9373/how-do-i-run-a-cron-job-on-a-mac

Answer (score 0):

An improvement to get a graphical dialog with zenity (uses GTK+). For Mac OS [cocoaDialog](http://mstratman.github.io/cocoadialog/) could be the thing to use.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    input=$(zenity --text "What are you doing?" --entry --width 400)
    retval=$?
    case $retval in
    0)
    what=$input;;
    1)
    what="";;
    esac
    echo `date` - $what >> ~/Documents/timelog/timelog_`date +%F`.txt
    sleep 3600
done
```